# how to work with time-dependent data in Lasso Cox regression in glmnet R package?

Tags: r, time-series, survival, cox-model, glmnet

I am trying to reproduce this study: http://stm.sciencemag.org/content/7/299/299ra122

I have time-dependent features like patient lab values and vital signs measurements, and also features like age, gender, etc that don't change in time. The paper says "we fit a Cox proportional hazards model using the time until the onset of septic shock as the supervisory signal". And "time-to-event models were learned as a Cox proportional hazards model with lasso regularization (glmnet R package, version 1.9-8"

I am new to survival analysis. I have done a lot of research but have not found one that has used glmnet cox regression with time dependent data. The only example I found is this: 
https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/master/inst/doc/Coxnet.R
The data (patient.data) columns are not explained and do not seem to be time dependent.

To feed my data to glmnet package, I know I should have a matrix x (one row for each patient and one column for each feature) and a matrix y (one column for each patient,one row for time of event for each patient and one row for status of event)

My question is, imagine I have 50 patients, and my features are age, gender, type of disease and blood pressure (measured every four hours for a month) and a lab value (measured every day for a month), what should my matrix x look like?

Comment: After reading the paper I think they did the following: they fitted N multiple models to predict the onset of septic shock from N specific time points Although, Cox assumes that every patient eventually experiences an event; however in this setting, not every patient develops septic shock. Would that mean that they only included the positive and interval-censored patients in their matrix to train the model and neglected the negatives? I am curious whether and how you have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you are using penalized?

It strikes me that with multiple ids per row it makes sense to use **cluster()** in the survival package and denote the patient the observation belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The main reason why  I am using penalized is that glmnet() was used in the original study that I am trying to reproduce. Also because I have 50+ covariates.

Comment: This paper with data prep for time-dependent covariates should explain what X needs to look like: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf

Comment: I already read that. It does not have an example that uses glmnet but I will try a similar approach and see if it works. Matrixs Y in glmnet has 2 rows and n(number of patients) columns, one row for event/censoring times and one for status(0 for censored and 1 for event). If I use the approach outlined in timedep.pdf, I have to have two rows for time in matrix Y (time1 and time2 or timestart and timestop), and I don't know if glmnet() will let me. I will try and update this post. Thanks for taking the time to help.